# Calculate values for subset of tensor values connected to the same neuron in optimizer

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow

I'm writing an optimizer in TensorFlow with python.

**How to calculate values for subsets of tensor values that are connected as incoming connections of neurons?**

---

For example, let's take the stochastic gradient descent optimizer with a momentum term. The momentum term is calculated for each connection individually. Now i want to calculate the momentum for one connection by calculating the mean of all momentum values of connections that are connected to the same neuron.

[image: Example connections]

In this picture, you can see the two connections that are both connected to neuron 3 as incoming connection. Both connections should be considered for the weight update of one connection. Normally the update for connection (1, 3) would only include the gradient(1, 3) and the momentum(1, 3). For the update of the connection (1, 3) i want to use the mean of the momentum(1, 3) and momentum(2, 3).

Let's have a look at a simple fully connected neural network with one input neuron, two hidden layers, two neurons per hidden layer and one output neuron:

[image: Example Neural Network]

If we look at the normal calculation of the momentum (called "accumulation" in the code) for the weight update for the connection between neuron 2 and neuron 5 we just consider the momentum of the last time.

We can see the normal "accumulation" update calculation from the python implementation below:

```
accumulation = self.get_slot(var, "a")
accumulation_update = grad + (mu_t * accumulation)
```

For the connection between neuron 2 and neuron 5 the accumulation looks like this:

[image: accumulationUpdate_{2,5} = grad_{2,5} + (\mu * accumulation_{2,5})]

This is the part that should change. The new momentum calculation should take the mean of all connections that are connected as incoming connections to the same neuron as the connection for which the weight update is calculated. Looking at the example neural network the "accumulation" value for the connection (2, 5) is the mean of the "accumulation" value of connection (2, 5) and (3, 5). These are all incoming connections of neuron 5.

The "accumulation" update changes in the following way:

```
accumulation = self.get_slot(var, "a")
accumulation_means = # Code to calculate all mean values for all neurons
accumulation_update = grad + (mu_t * accumulation_means) # Use the means for the accumulation_update
```

The accumulation update calculation for the connection (2, 5) is now calculated the following way:

```
accumulation_mean = (accumulation(2, 5) + accumulation(3, 5)) / 2
accumulation_update(2, 5) = grad(2, 5) + (mu_t * accumulation_mean)
```

This calculation is done the same way for every connection:

[image: calculation for all connections]

Here the python implementation of the stochastic gradient descent with momentum:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import state_ops
from tensorflow.python.training import optimizer


class SGDmomentum(optimizer.Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.001, momentum_term=0.9, use_locking=False, name="SGDmomentum"):
        super(SGDmomentum, self).__init__(use_locking, name)
        self._lr = learning_rate
        self._mu = momentum_term

        self._lr_t = None
        self._mu_t = None

    def _create_slots(self, var_list):
        for v in var_list:
            self._zeros_slot(v, "a", self._name)

    def _apply_dense(self, grad, var):
        lr_t = math_ops.cast(self._lr_t, var.dtype.base_dtype)
        mu_t = math_ops.cast(self._mu_t, var.dtype.base_dtype)
        accumulation = self.get_slot(var, "a")

        accumulation_update = grad + (mu_t * accumulation)
        accumulation_t = state_ops.assign(accumulation, accumulation_update, use_locking=self._use_locking)

        var_update = lr_t * accumulation_t
        var_t = state_ops.assign_sub(var, var_update, use_locking=self._use_locking)

        return control_flow_ops.group(*[var_t, accumulation_t])

    def _prepare(self):
        self._lr_t = ops.convert_to_tensor(self._lr, name="learning_rate")
        self._mu_t = ops.convert_to_tensor(self._mu, name="momentum_term")
```

The neural network i'm testing with (MNIST): https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py

**How to implement the described mean of "accumulation" values into the existing MWE code?**

---

*Just as a side note:*

*The MWE is not my real-life scenario. It is just a minimal working example to explain and work on the problem I'm trying to solve.*

*I'm writing the optimizer in python because I couldn't build TensorFlow on Windows and therefore couldn't compile the C++ files. I did put a lot of time in trying to build on Windows and i can't afford to waste more time on it. The optimizer in python is sufficient for me since I'm just prototyping at the moment.*

*I'm new to tensorflow and python. I can't find anything about this topic in the documentation. Linking me to a source would be great. Also the internal structure of tensors is not digestible for me and error messages I get while trying out things are just not understandable for me. Please keep that in mind when explaining something.*

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve summarized in 1-2 sentences?

Comment: It is not clear how do you plan to use these accumulated values.

Comment: So your idea is to implement a new SGD algorithm with another form of momentum? In the new algorithm, the accumulation (the new form of momentum) for one variable `x` is the mean of accumulations for all variables which have the same output neuron as `x`. If I am correct of understanding your algorithm, then suppose we have already got the traditional momentum (a matrix of same shape as the weight matrix), then your desired accumulation for `x` is just the mean of all elements in the same line of `x`. Isn't it?

Comment: @Seven I'm not sure what you mean with "the same line of x"? What do you mean with line?

Comment: Sorry... all elements in the same **row** of `x` in the matrix of traditional momentum.

Comment: Maybe it's clearer with equations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We take neuron 2,3,4,5 as example to compute the new momentum. We ignore the biases and consider only weights:

[image]

We use **W** for the matrix of weights, **G** for the corresponding gradients of **W**, **M** for the matrix of the corresponding momentum, \tilde{\bm{M}} is the mean matrix.

[image]

So the update of the new momentum is

[image]

I changed some code in the SGDmomentum class you proposed and run it on the MNIST example without error, which I think you have already done.

```
def _apply_dense(self, grad, var):
    lr_t = math_ops.cast(self._lr_t, var.dtype.base_dtype)
    mu_t = math_ops.cast(self._mu_t, var.dtype.base_dtype)
    accumulation = self.get_slot(var, "a")

    param_dims = len(accumulation.get_shape().as_list())
    if param_dims == 2:  # fc layer weights
        accumulation_mean = tf.reduce_mean(accumulation, axis=1, keep_dims=True)
    elif param_dims == 1:  # biases
        accumulation_mean = accumulation
    else:  # cnn? or others
        # TODO: improvement
        accumulation_mean = accumulation

    accumulation_update = grad + (mu_t * accumulation_mean)  # broadcasting is supported by tf.add()
    accumulation_t = state_ops.assign(accumulation, accumulation_update, use_locking=self._use_locking)

    var_update = lr_t * accumulation_t
    var_t = state_ops.assign_sub(var, var_update, use_locking=self._use_locking)

    return control_flow_ops.group(*[var_t, accumulation_t])
```

For training,

```
with tf.name_scope('train'):
    train_step = SGDmomentum(FLAGS.learning_rate, 0.9).minimize(cross_entropy)
    # train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate).minimize(
    #     cross_entropy)
```

For the moment, this algorithm converges less fast than traditional SGD with momentum on MNIST.

As for additional reading source, I don't know if Stanford CS231n can help you [Gradient Descent](http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-1/#gd) and [SGD with momentum](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#sgd). Probably, you have already knew that.

If you were still confused by the usage of matrix structure for the gradient tensors, then try to accept it because it's nearly no difference between a matrix and a single scalar here.

What I've done here is just transforming the calculation of each `accumulationUpdate_*` in your question to matrix form.

Comment: I'm really confused by your answer. It's new to me that the gradient tensor has a structure like the matrix you show. Do you have any source for this information and how would you use this solution in an actual tensorflow optimizer (the MWE from my question)?

Comment: In implementation, the gradient tensor has the same shape so that the tensor addition can be easily performed and each element corresponds to the computed gradient of the variable in the weight matrix. For the MWE, `accumulation = tf.reduce_mean(accumulation, axis=1, keepdims=True)` and `accumulation_update = grad + (mu_t * accumulation)` may help the problem, this works without error in `numpy`. But if I misunderstood your question, ...

Comment: I think you did understand my question correct. Some additional source to read up on this would be great for me to understand it. It doesn't work with the mnist network I'm testing with (bias dimension is 1 and reduce fails with error): Test Network: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py

Comment: Okay just don't changing the accumulation if the ndim is less then 2 did help. I will think about biases later. Sorry i'm new to python and tensorflow and these structures are all new to me. If you could add a source to your answer where i can read up on the form of the gradient tensor as you described it would be really great (i then would except your answer as complete).

Comment: I really like your answer know. What i meant with sources wasn't about SGD (this was just a example use that wasn't meant to make sense) it was about the structure of the gradient matrix (rows and columns for the connections with neuron). The formula you provided (G) is exactly what i was looking for but I wonder from where you know that it's structured that way? I couldn't find any documentation from tensorflow on this. The thing is I now only have the information from you that the structure is like that but non official documentation, document or paper stating this. How did you learn this?

Comment: Yeah... the pseudo-algorithm is **always** different from the implementation, but they do the same operations. If you do not use matrix form, you have to write two `for` loop. If you have read some Caffe code, you can see that when it allocates the memory for gradients, it gives the gradient the same shape as the weight. Or in TF, you get gradients by `tf.gradients()` or `optimizer.compute_gradients()`, and then you can check its information by `print gradient` or its shape by `print gradient.get_shape()`. You will find that the gradients have the same shape as the weights.